# what dose lockkeys in tikv api use for?

Tags: go, tidb, tikv

Recently, I was looking at tikv's api document. There is a LockKey api in transaction. When I call it for operation, I directly panic.
i have serval question?

1. i want to know why it panic
2. what does the lockKeys api use for?
   can any help me

```golang
    txn1, txn2 := begin(), begin()
    fmt.Println("txn1 before:", txn1.IsPessimistic())
    txn1.SetOption(kv.Pessimistic, true)
    fmt.Println("txn1 after:", txn1.IsPessimistic())

    fmt.Println("txn2 before:", txn2.IsPessimistic())
    txn2.SetOption(kv.Pessimistic, true)
    fmt.Println("txn2 after:", txn2.IsPessimistic())

    err := txn1.Set(k2, v22)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    err = txn1.Set(k1, v22)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    lockCtx1 := &kv.LockCtx{ForUpdateTS: txn1.StartTS(), WaitStartTime: time.Now()}
    err = txn1.LockKeys(context.Background(), lockCtx1, k1,k2)
    if err!=nil{
        panic(err)
    }
    err = txn2.Set(k2, v23)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    err = txn2.Set(k1, v23)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    lockCtx2 := &kv.LockCtx{ForUpdateTS: txn2.StartTS(), WaitStartTime: time.Now()}
    err = txn2.LockKeys(context.Background(), lockCtx2, k1,k2)
    if err!=nil{
        panic(err)
    }
    err = txn1.Commit(context.Background())
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(get(k2))
    err = txn2.Commit(context.Background())
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
```

panic stack is :

```golang
panic: runtime error: index out of range [0] with length 0
goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/pingcap/tidb/store/tikv.actionPessimisticLock.handleSingleBatch(0xc0002d6380, 0xc00036c3c0, 0xc0002d6400, 0x4, 0x1, 0x2, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc000288bd0, ...)
        /Users/go/pkg/mod/github.com/pingcap/tidb@v1.1.0-beta.0.20210419034717-00632fb3c710/store/tikv/2pc.go:922 +0x1442
github.com/pingcap/tidb/store/tikv.(*twoPhaseCommitter).doActionOnBatches(0xc00036c3c0, 0xc0002d6400, 0x4d430e0, 0xc0002d6380, 0xc0002d6500, 0x1, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0)
        /Users/go/pkg/mod/github.com/pingcap/tidb@v1.1.0-beta.0.20210419034717-00632fb3c710/store/tikv/2pc.go:678 +0x110
github.com/pingcap/tidb/store/tikv.(*twoPhaseCommitter).doActionOnGroupMutations(0xc00036c3c0, 0xc0002d6400, 0x4d430e0, 0xc0002d6380, 0xc0002d6480, 0x1, 0x1, 0x2, 0x0)
        /Users/go/pkg/mod/github.com/pingcap/tidb@v1.1.0-beta.0.20210419034717-00632fb3c710/store/tikv/2pc.go:623 +0x442
github.com/pingcap/tidb/store/tikv.(*twoPhaseCommitter).doActionOnMutations(0xc00036c3c0, 0xc0002d6400, 0x4d430e0, 0xc0002d6380, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc000288bd0, 0x2, 0x2, ...)
        /Users/go/pkg/mod/github.com/pingcap/tidb@v1.1.0-beta.0.20210419034717-00632fb3c710/store/tikv/2pc.go:513 +0x1c3
github.com/pingcap/tidb/store/tikv.(*twoPhaseCommitter).pessimisticLockMutations(...)
        /Users/go/pkg/mod/github.com/pingcap/tidb@v1.1.0-beta.0.20210419034717-00632fb3c710/store/tikv/2pc.go:1291
github.com/pingcap/tidb/store/tikv.(*tikvTxn).LockKeys(0xc0000f60c0, 0x4d44e60, 0xc00012c000, 0xc0002d6380, 0xc000288ba0, 0x2, 0x2, 0x0, 0x0)
        /Users/go/pkg/mod/github.com/pingcap/tidb@v1.1.0-beta.0.20210419034717-00632fb3c710/store/tikv/txn.go:446 +0x5f9
main.testTxn(0xc00003e068, 0x4, 0x4, 0xc00003e088, 0x4, 0x4, 0xc00003e096, 0x7, 0x7, 0xc00003e0a0, ...)
```

it occure in [where painc happen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVlBa.png), m is nil

the go mod is below

```golang
go 1.14

require (
    github.com/juju/errors v0.0.0-20200330140219-3fe23663418f
    github.com/juju/testing v0.0.0-20210324180055-18c50b0c2098 // indirect
    github.com/pingcap/parser v0.0.0-20210107054750-53e33b4018fe
    github.com/pingcap/tidb v1.1.0-beta.0.20210419034717-00632fb3c710
    golang.org/x/net v0.0.0-20210226172049-e18ecbb05110
)
```

Comment: the api is in https://github.com/pingcap/tidb/blob/master/kv/kv.go

Comment: Please share the entire panic, not just the stack trace.

Comment: i have update the question,if you have any idea pls tell me,appreciate

Comment: You're using v1.1.0-beta and the panic was on 2pc.go line 922, which doesn't appear to exist in the source. You might want to raise this with the maintainers of the module.

Answer (score 0):

For question2, `lockKeys` will lock the entry for the keys you provided in KVStore(TiKV)

For question1, please share the whole panic stack.

Comment: i have update the question,if you have any idea pls tell me,appreciate